# Ошибка при обновлении Swagger

Tags: java, spring, swagger

Обновлял версию Swagger c 2.7.0 на 2.8.0. В POM

```
        <!-- Swagger -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

В контексте.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true" secured-annotations="enabled"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="swagger-ui.html" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/" />
```

Выдаёт ошибку

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'; nested exception is com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty.allowEmptyValue()Z
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:176)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:51)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:346)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:149)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:112)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:770)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:483)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:664)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:630)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:678)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:490)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:626)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:405)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:875)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:346)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1380)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1342)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:772)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:259)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:518)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:405)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:106)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:372)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.hc.jp.WebServer.start(WebServer.java:62)
at org.hc.jp.Main.start(Main.java:42)
at org.hc.jp.Main.main(Main.java:30)
at com.cdek.client.web.CLMWebServer.main(CLMWebServer.java:11)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понимаю, у вас ошибка в конфигурации Docket.

В [этом](https://github.com/fragaLY/Status-Quo/blob/master/statusquo-web/src/main/java/sq/vk/web/configuration/mvc/SwaggerConfig.java) репозитории есть необходимый setup.